# Compilation & linking of linked LIST ADT

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

Am having a problem with linking my implementation file in Microsoft Visual C++, and getting this error:

Compiling...
Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
slList.cpp
Linking...
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file ".\Debug\slList.obj"
Error executing link.exe.

Can somebody please assist?

Answer (score 0):

That usually means that

1. you either are using the file
2. you don't have access to it

Mor information on that error [here](http://vcfaq.mvps.org/lang/10.htm)

Try doing a cleanup on the solution then rebuild. If that doenst work just remove the debug / release folders and compile.

Also if you want you can take a look at my Linked List implementation [here](http://frw.se/List_CPP/), it's a couple of years old though, was for a course at my university.